# Expand & Collapse function, if/else statement in Atom Editor

Tags: atom-editor

So let's say you have a lot of lines of code and some of them have functions, if/else statements closed like this:

[image]
 How would I do it to expand every single one at the same time instead of opening manually? (And also vice versa, how would I collapse  every single one without doing it manually?)

Comment: You're probably looking for "expand" or "collapse", rather than "open" or "close"; also I've seen "fold" and "unfold" used. That might help with your searching.

Comment: yes that, well thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you open the command pallete by doing `command + shift + p` and type "fold" you'll see a command and the keyboard shortcut to the side!

[image: From the Atom command pallette]